# How to redirect expired users with passport.js and Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-routing, passport.js

A bit of background:

- I am using Passport.js to handle login from serverside.
- Angular routing is used on the client side in a one-page-app

The issue:

In my server router i have middleware which ensure users are logged in when requesting certain content, namely:

```
function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.render('index.ejs');
};
```

used in routes such as:

```
app.get('/SomethingForLoggedUsers', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){...
```

My problem is that if the user is on the website (on the part handled by Angular router) and their session is expired `res.render('index.ejs');` does not work. My feeling is that angular routing has to do with the fact that index.ejs is not shown, but I don't manage to fix the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem.

In my angular controller I have:

```
$http.get('/SomethingForLoggedUsers').success(function(data) {
if(!data.user)$window.location.href="/login";
```

and in the server I return user:null everytime the user is not logged, namely:

```
function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.json({user:null});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your solution is that with angular, it is possible that the user may be doing some client operations and not making a request on the server.

In angular, I have seen two common approaches to this problem:

Handle this fully on the client, there is an open source ng-idle directive that can help with this. When the user times out on the client, you can log them out of the application using passport

Handle this with support from the server, there is an open source angular-http-auth module that can help handle HTTP 401 / 403 from the server.  This means your code would do:

```
function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
}
    res.writeHead(401);
    res.end();
};
```

I hope this information helps you understand what is possible in Angular.